# Error "bad indentation of a mapping entry" in Swagger editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

In the OpenAPI definition below, the parameter definition causes the parser error `"bad indentation of a mapping entry"`. What is wrong? Error at "properties" (last 5th line)

```
responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json;charset=UTF-8:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  creationTime:
                    type: string
                    format: date-time
                    description: >-
                      The date and time the response was created in GMT time
                      with a format of "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                    example: '03-12-2019 14:05:35.182-0500'
                  response:
                    type: array
                    description: ''
                      properties:
                        recordID:
                          type: string
                          maxLength: 20
                        externalID:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the `properties` keyword is indented more than its sibling `type` and `description` keywords.

```yaml
                  response:
                    type: array
                    description: ''
                      properties:     # <---- Indentation doesn't match the sibling
                                      #       `type` and `description` keywords
```

However, `type: array` schemas need `items`, not `properties`.

It looks like the `response` key is either *missing* some keywords or has *extra* keywords. The correct definition for `response` would be:

```yaml
                  response:
                    type: object      # <----------
                    description: ''
                    properties:       # <----------
                      recordID:
                        type: string
                        maxLength: 20
                      externalID:
                        ...
```

or

```yaml
                  response:
                    type: array
                    description: ''
                    items:             # <----------
                      type: object     # <----------
                      properties:      # <----------
                        recordID:
                          type: string
                          maxLength: 20
                        externalID:
                          ...
```

depending on what you need.